# Formatting time from in java swing formatted text field

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I got this assignment to make a timer app with two options, "on time" and countdown" In both cases an app has to open a new window where colors are changing. I'm having problem with first option, for some reason I cant parse time to formatted text field.

I have tried several methods, sometimes it crashes and sometime it just starts working regardless of given time.

```
{
    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
st=true;
    Object set = jFormatted.getText();
    String setTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(set);  
    String appTime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(appTime);  
    try   
      SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
      Date d1 = form.parse(setTime);  
      Date d2 = form.parse(appTime1);           
      razlika = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();  
     catch (Exception e) {  
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());  

}
```

Comment: What is `jFormatted`? What is `appTime`?

Comment: If `jFormatted` is a `JTextField`, then `getText()` returns a `String`, so why are you assigning to an `Object` field and doing weird things to get a `String`?

Comment: jFormatted is jFormattedTextField. I've tried this also:

Comment: Sorry I hit enter too soon. I tried this:    String myDateString = jFormatted.getText();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDateString);

Comment: ... and? ... What was wrong with that? Assuming the field's text is something like `14:37:42`, that should work fine.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your time. The problem is, when I input time, to set when the app will go on, using that line of code, I'm getting this error "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date", and many more.  I really don't know what to do. Any advice is more then welcome.

Comment: And what is the value returned by `getText()`?

Comment: I got this parsing problem, now it parses just fine. Thank you very much for your time. I forgot to add date.toString();

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).